# Installing lisp/opengl on FreeBSD

Tags: opengl, lisp, freebsd

I'm trying to make some simple graphics with **OpenGL** and **LISP** but I can't **install** the cl-opengl library on **FreeBSD**, so:

> How do I install cl-opengl (or something similar) on FreeBSD?

Comment: @Grrr: I tried manually downloading the package, putting it in correct directories etc; I tried asdf, I tried other libraries... I can't say exactly what went wrong because I tried many different things. I think I am missing some steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cl-opengl depends on native opengl libraries for the given platform. It is basically a lispy wrapper around **libGl**. Make sure you have one installed before attempting to install cl-opengl.

cl-opengl work with any lisp implementation that supports **cffi**. This means SBCL, ECL, CCL, ABCL and probably CLisp are ok.